# Can a server setting keep a page from opening?

Tags: iis, iis-6, html

I have a page with the following form:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="wrong_1.htm" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="A. Public / Community View ">
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, a page with the correct URL is opened as expected, but a 404 results. Then when I place the cursor in the address bar and enter, the page appears.

This doesn't happen when the page is run locally, so I wonder if a server setting (url rewrite?) is getting in the way. I'm baffled.

The server is Microsoft-IIS/6.0

Answer (score 1):

There are two factors changing when you click in the URL bar and press enter:

- You are submitting a GET request, not a POST request.
- Your browser is not sending a `Referer` header.

Based on the information provided, it will be difficult to steer you in a more specific direction. Those are the directions I would suggest looking in to -- make sure whatever is handling that POST request isn't getting confused by one of those two items.